# Can't get selenium to work on java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am loading up a webdriver and I got an error which got fixed by adding guava, but now I get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
```

I have `selenium-java-2.38.0`. I went to sourcefourge and got a json jar but that didn't help. Not sure what specific one I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the standalone package. You shouldn't have to search for any further dependency with it.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar